# Looping through strings?

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to learn Ruby recently by converting simple programs I've written in Python.

In Python, I have a program which defines a function which takes a string and returns a new string which is the old string with a dash in between each character.

So, "hello" would be returned as "-h-e-l-l-o".

In Python this is very simple as you just loop through each character of the original string and add it to a new string plus a dash.

However, this seems more difficult in Ruby since I can't just loop through a string in Ruby, as far as I can tell.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: You wrote "a dash between each character", but you have a dash (hyphen) at even the beginning of the string. Which?

Comment: Basically, I want to build up a new string from the old string. In python I can use a for loop to loop through a string. Ruby only seems to let you loop through an array, so maybe I should concert the string to an array which seems easy enough to do.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.. you can

```
"hello".chars.map { |c| "-#{c}" }.join
 # => "-h-e-l-l-o"
```

See more Ruby power

```
string = 'hello'
"-%s" * string.size % string.chars
# => "-h-e-l-l-o"
```

Look doc for [`#*`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-2A) and [`#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-25) .

Comment: Good trick with `%`. However, on 1.9.3, `string.chars` returns enumerator. So `.to_a` might help.

Comment: Gah! I hope I never have to maintain any of your code :-)

Comment: @DarekNędza Thanks for your valuable comment.. I am in Ruby 2.0, 2.1 , so not aware of 1.9.3 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this...

```
"hello".split('').join('-')
```

Hmm but it doesn't give you the leading one.  But you get the idea.

If you really need the leading '-' you can do this....

```
"hello".split('').reduce(''){|s,c| s += '-' + c}
```

Which I have now learned can be done much more nicely as:

```
"hello".chars.reduce(''){|s,c| s += '-' + c}
```

Comment: look this `"-h-e-l-l-o"`

Answer (score 1):

What mean "loop through string". You loop through characters, so in Ruby you write exactly that:

```
'abba'.each_char { |c| puts c }
```

But you are trying to achieve something else (you have written something else and your example was something else). There are 2 ways to achieve what you say:

```
'hello'.chars.join('-')
```

or

```
'hello'.gsub(//, '-')
```

Both will return the same string: `h-e-l-l-o`.

To achieve your example you can use regexp:

```
'hello'.gsub(/(\w)/, '-\1')
```

or map

```
'hellp'.each_char.map { |c| "-#{c}" }.join
```

But the second one will IMHO be a little bit slower.

Comment: `'hello'.gsub /./, '-\0'` too.

Answer (score 1):

For completion, a method that does not use an explicit iterator:

```
([''] + s.split('')).join('-')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way - just for fun:

```
'-' + 'hello'.chars * '-'
# => "-h-e-l-l-o"
```

Here I'm using [`#*`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-2A) which for an array of strings acts as [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-join), by connection each pair of chars with a `'-'`. Instead of adding a mock object to the beginning of the array for the first dash, I opted to simply stick a `'-'` at the beginning...

Comment: The good ol' `*`. Now, don't just throw it out there, 'splain to the OP how it works. It's part of teaching how to fish.